# Deleting text between brackets in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, newlines, brackets

I need to delete everything between {} example below

Before:

```
ParticleEffects
{
    animation = "distort"
        0 = "mid Metadata/Effects/misc/distort/distort.pet"
}
```

After:

```
ParticleEffects
{
}
```

the } bracket has to be below { they can't be next to each other like this {} or else it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution

- Find what: `\{(.*?)\}`
- Replace with: `\{\n\}`
- Search Mode: Regular expression
- [x] matches newline (must be selected)

info

- "{" and "}" must be escaped with "\"
- "\n" inserts newline character

Comment: works thank you for quick help.

Answer (score 1):

I Used the regex expression as below in the notpad++ once the regex radio-option was selected. It removes everything that comes between the brackets.

```
 <.*?>
```

like ex `<p data-attribute="" id="as8asdj3ea90">` or simple `</p>` will also be removed.

this worked for me in removing everything between arrow brackets in Notepad++