# (Notepad++) Delete text between brackets but not from all brackets

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, newlines, brackets

So I posted [a question earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/1453686/deleting-text-between-brackets-in-notepad) and got answered by user Dmytro Dzyubak, everything worked, but now I'm trying to make it work faster. More details below.

Before:

```
SkinMesh
{
    skin = "Art/Models/Effects/enviro_effects/misc/blood_orb/BloodOrb.sm"
}

SoundEvents
{
    soundbank = "_Effects_misc_blood_orbs.bank"
    animation = "enter"
        0 = "Audio/Sound Effects/Misc/BloodOrb/Start_$(#).ogg@2 120 0 0.1 0.1 0 -1 0 1 1"
    animation = "exit"
        0 = "Audio/Sound Effects/Misc/BloodOrb/End_$(#).ogg@1.6 115 0 0 0 0 -1 0 1 1"
    animation = "idle"
        0 = "Audio/Sound Effects/Misc/BloodOrb/Orb_$(#).loop.ogg@0.4 115 0 0 0 0 -1 0 10 4.5"
}

BoneGroups
{
    bone_group = "mid false mid jnt_orb_01 "
    bone_group = "cyl false mid cyl "
    bone_group = "explode false jnt_orb_01 up_explode "
    bone_group = "explodecyl false jnt_orb_01 cyl_explode1 "
    bone_group = "midparticle false mini_orb1 mini_orb_particleup_02 "
}
```

As you can see, there are a bunch of brackets. Is it possible to delete only text inside:

```
SkinMesh
{
    skin = "Art/Models/Effects/enviro_effects/misc/blood_orb/BloodOrb.sm"
}
```

and

```
SoundEvents
{
    soundbank = "_Effects_misc_blood_orbs.bank"
    animation = "enter"
        0 = "Audio/Sound Effects/Misc/BloodOrb/Start_$(#).ogg@2 120 0 0.1 0.1 0 -1 0 1 1"
    animation = "exit"
        0 = "Audio/Sound Effects/Misc/BloodOrb/End_$(#).ogg@1.6 115 0 0 0 0 -1 0 1 1"
    animation = "idle"
        0 = "Audio/Sound Effects/Misc/BloodOrb/Orb_$(#).loop.ogg@0.4 115 0 0 0 0 -1 0 10 4.5"
}
```

and leave BoneGroups untouched?

Here is an example of how it should look:

```
SkinMesh
{
}

SoundEvents
{
}

BoneGroups
{
    bone_group = "mid false mid jnt_orb_01 "
    bone_group = "cyl false mid cyl "
    bone_group = "explode false jnt_orb_01 up_explode "
    bone_group = "explodecyl false jnt_orb_01 cyl_explode1 "
    bone_group = "midparticle false mini_orb1 mini_orb_particleup_02 "
}
```

Comment: "So i posted a question earlier and got answered by user Dmytro Dzyubak" please provide a link.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(?:SkinMesh|SoundEvents)\s+\{\K.+?(?=\})`
- Replace with: `\n`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b                  # word boundary
(?:                 # start non capture group
    SkinMesh        # literally "SkinMesh"
  |                 # OR
    SoundEvents     # literally "SoundEvents"
)                   # end group
\s+                 # 1 or more any spaces (including linebreak)
\{                  # openning curly bracket
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this position
.+?                 # 1 or more any characters including linebreak
(?=\})              # positive lookahead, make sure we have a closing curly bracket after.
```

**Replacement:**

```
\n      # linefeed, you may use \r\n
```

**Result for given example:**

```
SkinMesh
{
}

SoundEvents
{
}

BoneGroups
{
    bone_group = "mid false mid jnt_orb_01 "
    bone_group = "cyl false mid cyl "
    bone_group = "explode false jnt_orb_01 up_explode "
    bone_group = "explodecyl false jnt_orb_01 cyl_explode1 "
    bone_group = "midparticle false mini_orb1 mini_orb_particleup_02 "
}
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I won't be winning any RegEx Golf with this answer, but it works.

Using the guidelines in [Dmytro Dzyubak's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1453692/1055752) (i.e. search in RegEx mode with ". matches newline" checked), make the following changes:

Find: `^(S[^\r\n]+)(\r?\n?)\{(.*?)\}`
Replace: `\1\2\{\2\}`

Info:
It now ensures that the line preceding the brackets starts with a capital S.
It also catches the line ending and replaces it (so that you don't end up with mixed line endings).
`\1` and `\2` in the Replace expression refer to the parentheses groups in the Find expression.

Comment: This will also remove `Send{ blah blah}` or `DontSend{ blah blah}`

Comment: @Toto, this is true. I forgot to put the ^ before the S to ensure that the S was at the beginning of the line. I'll update it. Thanks! (I did mention that it was targeting all lines that start with S in the Info section of my answer, but I see that your answer more precisely answers his question and better explains what is happening. Since he had previously asked a question for this same type of thing, I assumed he was more wanting to learn RegEx and different ways to quickly apply it in Notepad++ than only be able to target those two words.) directly.

Comment: @Toto, your answer is a far more thorough and elegant answer. I also didn't realize Notepad++ supported some of those features of RegEx. If I had enough reputation, I'd upvote it. ;)

Comment: Thank you :).....